# Location Manager's requestLocationUpdates called only once

Tags: android, location

I am calling the method and expect location updates multiple times:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps",0 ,0, loc_listener);
```

My `loc_listener` is defined as:

```
LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener() {
    private final String TAG = "xoxoxo.LocationListener";

    public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
        Intent locationAlert = new Intent("xoxoxo.LOCATION_CHANGED")
                .putExtra("target_location", l);
        sendBroadcast(locationAlert);
        // locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0 ,0, this);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String p) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Provider enabled");
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String p) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Provider disabled");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String p, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Status changed");
    }
};
```

Defined as is, I will only get an update once, both on HTC Evo 2.2 and 2.2 + Google API emulator.
The hack to get multiple updates is to uncomment the line which registers for updates on each update:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0 ,0, this);
```

Have you guys seen anything like this?

Comment: You can use NETWORK_PROVIDER to get fast location...

Comment: My application requires only fine location. Without it, much of functionality is lost.

Comment: for gps provider you require open sky condition so that it can update very quickly and accurately but in case you are inside the building you need to implement network provider due to get at least updated location which is less accurate as compare to GPS.

Comment: Anand, again, I can't use network location. User would always be outside.

Answer (score 17):

I have never seen the issue. The following is my code to test LocationManager and LocationListener. It works as expected when LocationListener is implemented as an anonymous class.

```
package com.test.locationmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LocationManagerStatus extends Activity {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private TextView textView;
    private final LocationListener gpsLocationListener =new LocationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            final String tvTxt = textView.getText().toString();
            switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                textView.setText(tvTxt + "GPS available again\n");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                textView.setText(tvTxt + "GPS out of service\n");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                textView.setText(tvTxt + "GPS temporarily unavailable\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()
                    + "GPS Provider Enabled\n");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()
                    + "GPS Provider Disabled\n");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()
                    + "New GPS location: "
                    + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLatitude()) + ", "
                    + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLongitude()) + "\n");
        }
    };
    private final LocationListener networkLocationListener =
                                                        new LocationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
            final String tvTxt = textView.getText().toString();
            switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                textView.setText(tvTxt + "Network location available again\n");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                textView.setText(tvTxt + "Network location out of service\n");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                textView.setText(tvTxt
                        + "Network location temporarily unavailable\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()
                    + "Network Provider Enabled\n");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()
                    + "Network Provider Disabled\n");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString()
                    + "New network location: "
                    + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLatitude()) + ", "
                    + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLongitude()) + "\n");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0,
                networkLocationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                3000, 0, gpsLocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
    }
}
```