# I can not get the location from Location manager in android

Tags: android, gps

In my app I will check the GPS is enabled or not. If not enabled i will redirect the page to GPS settings.

After enable the GPS i will get the location from LocationManager. But I can not get the location.

Here I attached my code.

```
if (isGPSEnabled())
{
getLocation();
}



private boolean isGPSEnabled() {
        boolean gpsEnabled = false;
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            gpsEnabled = true;
            return gpsEnabled;
        } else {
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
        return gpsEnabled;
    }



private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage(
                        "GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                            }
                        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }



private void getLocation() {
        LocationManager  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {

        }
    }



    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Double lat = (Double) (location.getLatitude());
        Double lng = (Double) (location.getLongitude());
    }
```

Please tell me what mistake i did?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you testing with a real device or with the android emulator? If you are using a device, which one is it? Bear in mind also that GPS doesn't work so good indoor, maybe it's better if you try outdoor or near a window (I've faced something similar in the past). However, the LastKnownLocation strategy should work as you said.

Comment: Maythis link help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772686/location-managers-requestlocationupdates-called-only-once

Comment: What mistake i did?? I think Every thing is correct. When i try to run my app without using of GPS enable method(i hide the method, and i manually on the GPS), it is working. When i try to add the GPS Enable method the location is not showing..

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you never ask for a new location from LocationManager.

```
private void getLocation() {
    LocationManager  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(provider, myLocationListener, null);
    }
}
```